# Error in Zoo Visitor entries after installing Field Pack, remains after uninstall

Tags: pixelandtonic, zoo-visitor, field-pack

I installed Pixel & Tonic's [Field Pack v2.1.1](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack) for better checkboxes. I only installed the checkbox field type. Immediately after, when I try to edit a channel entry within my Zoo Visitor channel, I get a white screen with the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'field_id_0' in 'field list'
SELECT `field_id_0` FROM (`exp_channel_data`) WHERE `channel_id` = '0'
Filename: fieldtypes/checkboxes/ft.checkboxes.php
Line Number: 312
```

When I uninstall Field Pack checkboxes and delete all the Field Pack files, the error still appears.

It looks to me that the error is within the native EE checkboxes fieldtype file, but the last modification date on that file is long before I installed Field Pack, so I don't think the addon modified the file and broke something.

I'm at a loss. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was that in a checkbox field, neither "Populate the menu manually" or "Populate the menu from another channel field" was selected. I'm not sure how I managed to not have either radio button ticked, but that was the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue, and making sure 'Populate the menu manually' was set fixed the issue. However, I'm not using Field Pack. Are you perhaps using "Field Editor"?